# How do I connect a polyethylene water supply line to my refrigerator?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a Kenmore refrigerator (model 53552200), and want to connect a 1/4" polyethylene line for the incoming water.  I'm guessing the connection is something similar to right portion of the following image, but want to make sure before I go to hardware store:
[image]
(i.e. brass compression nut, brass tube insert and with a plastic "sleeve"; although 1/4" in my case). Does this sound right?

When tightening it, what is a good rule of thumb to avoid over- and under-tightening the connection?

**Update / secondary question:** I bought this [Watts Ander-Lign Compression Nut](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905075716/http://www.watts.com/pages/_products_details.asp?pid=6399) from the store, which says it is compatible with plastic tubing. Does a nut like this need a plastic sleeve? If not, would a different compression nut---that is compatible with a plastic sleeve---be preferred?  NOTE: the picture above is NOT the Watts Ander-Lign compression nut I have---I just needed a picture of a plastic sleeve to aid my question

**update  2:** I haven't found a definitive answer on this yet, so any help you can provide is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: I generally go 1/8 to 1/4 turn past hand tight. If you see a drip go a little more. You are correct in that too tight can be as bad as too loose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watts claims their Ander-Lign fitting is universal and specifically says it can be used with plastic tubing carrying water.

The fact that they are using an insert makes the fitting stronger than the usual water filter/frig water supply fittings which are simple "push in" type fittings.

Here's an example of the other style:
http://www.freedrinkingwater.com/parts/fittings/jg-whitepoly-male-connector.htm

I think you should be fine.

Comment: For the Ander-Lign fitting, do you know if I use it with a plastic sleeve (as shown in my picture above), or does the built-in "sleeve-looking item" fulfill this purpose?

Comment: The Ander-Lign fitting you got is described as having "a captive sleeve". If that is true, it doesn't seem as though you have a choice in the sleeve you use.

A very soft plastic tube (vinyl) may work better with a plastic sleeve but you're using polyethylene which is much harder than vinyl and should be ok with the metal sleeve.

Your picture is not of the Ander-Lign fitting you used so it is not definitive.

Comment: Thanks Philip.  I will make a note in my post that the Ander-Lign fitting I'm referring to is not the one in my picture to avoid confusion by others

Answer (score 2):

Don't use plastic tubing if you can avoid it. Sooner or later it will develop a pin hole or pull out of the fitting resulting in water damage. A braided stainless line is much more durable, especially for a refrigerator ice maker installation. A 10 ft braided line is about the same cost as a plastic line kit.